# Treat \n as raw text in python?

Tags: python

Question, so i need to send \n in a packet now, but python treats it as a EOL. How can i tell it to treat \n as raw text and part of the packet exactly?

`logcom = "LOGON\n Protocol-Version: 2.0\n App-type: Windows x86\n Operator: PC_CLIENT\n name: " + pal_user + "\n capabilities: 4\n"`

I need to send all of it in one packet, but it treats \n as EOL when the packet has multiple lines, but not when its just LOGON\n

`socket.sendall("'LOGON\n
                          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

The error^

Comment: It would help us in helping you if you described your problem a bit more or if you posted some code. Are you using tcp/udp sockets or RAW?

Comment: im using a TCP socket, and the first part of the packet is LOGON\n , but it treats \n as part of code, but it needs to be send in the packet CODE: 'logcom = "LOGON\n
Protocol-Version: 2.0\n
App-type: Windows x86\n
Operator: PC_CLIENT\n
name: " + pal_user + "\n
capabilities: 4\n"
'

Comment: I am assuming you're using `socket.sendall('LOGON\n')`, is that correct? If so, then the `sendall` function sends the whole string as is, along with whitespace characters such as `\n`.

Comment: Could you post `logcom` for us to see?

Comment: Python sends any data over a socket without interpretation. I don't know what you mean by "treats \n as EOL". Can you show more of your actual code?

Comment: It is not a socket error, it's a syntax error.  I suspect a missing closing quote.  You need to post your code.

Answer (score 2):

You almost surely have a missing closing quote on a line.  Just use it like this:

```
logcom = "LOGON\n Protocol-Version: 2.0\n App-type: Windows x86\n Operator: PC_CLIENT\n name: " + pal_user + "\n capabilities: 4\n"
socket.sendall(logcom)
```

If you want to split it over several lines in your source code, as you have in your question, you should write it like this with triple quotes:

```
logcom = """LOGON
Protocol-Version: 2.0
App-type: Windows x86
Operator: PC_CLIENT
name: {}
capabilities: 4
""".format(pal_user)
socket.sendall(logcom)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send the '\' in the '\n', then all you need to do is escape the character.  Thus, you should be sending:

```
logcom = "LOGON\\n Protocol-Version: 2.0\\n App-type: Windows x86\\n Operator: PC_CLIENT\\n name: " + pal_user + "\\n capabilities: 4\\n"
```

If you need to send the data with the newlines included, I would try using `socket.send` in a loop.

Comment: Or put `r` before the string literal.

Comment: well i need to send the entire \n in the packet, but it gets treated as a EOL no matter what

Comment: like the packet structure is 'LOGON\n
Protocol-Version: 2.0\n
App-type: Windows x86\n
Operator: PC_CLIENT\n
name: " + pal_user + "\n
capabilities: 4\n'

Comment: Is the problem that it's only sending a piece at a time?  Shouldn't you just keep reading?

Comment: here lets say    `socket.sendall("'LOGON\n
                          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` i have to send it all in **ONE** packet and include the **\n** part **IN** the packet, i dont know how to explain  it much better

Comment: @user1792652: that's exactly the error message you would get if you just hit return after the `\n` and didn't close the quote.  [You seem to be using both `"` and `'` at the start, which seems a little strange to me too.]

Comment: As an aside, I wouldn't trust TCP for sending everything in a single packet.  Because it's a stream abstraction, it's allowed to break up packets.  But I'm guessing you can't choose the server...